# How to toggle icons in ngfor rows?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3, ngx-datatable

Good day,
The following code will toggle all the icons for ngfor rows.  How to toggle just the icon being clicked?

```
<ng-template #clickState let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-row="row" let-expanded ="expanded" ngx-datatable-cell-template >

<strong>{{row.dbColumn1}}</strong>
    <i class="fa fa-external-link"
     style="float:right;padding-top: 4px; vertical-align:bottom"
     *ngIf="!clickState.clicked"
     (click)="clickState.clicked=true"
     (click)="onVisible($event,row.dbColumn1,row,rowIndex)">h</i>

     <i class="fa fa-clone"
     style="float:right;padding-top: 4px; vertical-align:bottom"
     *ngIf="clickState.clicked" 
     (click)="clickState.clicked=false"
     (click)="onVisible($event,row.dbColumn1,row,rowIndex)">h</i>

  </ng-template>
```

Thanks.
LHLK

Comment: ngFor code share it to know more and onvisible function code also share

Comment: Basically I just followed this link: https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/demo/basic/row-detail.component.ts and would like to change the individual icon.  FYI LHLK